# I'm trying to use <a> tag on an array

Tags: angularjs, anchor

```
<div class="shared-by-list" ng-show="dashpost.showPostSharedByList">
  <span><small><strong><em>Shared by: </em></strong></small></span>
  <span><small>{{dashpost.postSharedByList}}</small></span> 
</div>
```

In the above code `dashpost.postSharedByList` is an array of names who shared that particular post. I have to include an `<a>` tag with `href` pointing to that specific profile. The problem is the hyperlink is applied to all the names in the array. I want different links for different elements in the array. Please help!

Comment: Show us the code which has the problem.

Comment: can you post full code here ?

Comment: The output I'll get with the code I posted is something like this _Shared by: Peter Jackson, Marshall Mathers, prasanth narasimha_ ................I want to include a anchor tag for each of them and the links differ in only the user id ...somewhat like href="#/profile/{{userId}} . When I tried , it is making all those names as a single link and when I clicked , It opens the profile of the first user.

Comment: userId has not been cited before and I cannot figure where to find such information in the code you posted. Can you please edit your post adding more code?

Comment: @morels   I'm sorry I can't post the full code. But 'dashpost.postSharedByList' contains first and last names of all the users who shared that particular post seperated by commas .It's size is not constant it may increase or decrease.i'm using loopback for DB API and mongoDb as DB

Comment: If you want us to show where the bug is in your code, and how to fix it, you need to show us your code. Sayin "I did something like this, and it did something like that" is not useful. Show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="shared-by-list" ng-show="dashpost.showPostSharedByList">
  <div ng-repeat="postSharedBy in dashpost.postSharedByList">
    <span><small><strong><em>Shared by: </em></strong></small></span>
    <span><small><a ng-href="#/profile/{{postSharedBy}}">{{postSharedBy}}</a></small></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

It would be better if the list would contain objects structured like so:

```
{name: "element name", anchorname: "element anchor" }
```

Anyway it is up to you the choice.

Comment: It's not working . It's not displaying those names now. Do I need to make any changes in the controller?

Comment: i don't know if you don't post your controller. what is the problem? the rendered div list is still `<div class="shared-by-list ng-hide"` even if the js list is not empty?

Comment: The output I'll get with the code I posted is something like this                                            Shared by: Peter Jackson, Marshall Mathers, prasanth narasimha                        I want to include a anchor tag for each of them and the links differ in only the user id ...somewhat like href="#/profile/{{userId}} . When I tried , it is making all those names as a single link and when I clicked , It opens the profile of the first user.

Comment: @PrashanthNarasimha edited solution reading the whole situation you presented.

Comment: _Shared by: P
Shared by: e
Shared by: t
Shared by: e
Shared by: r
Shared by: 
Shared by: J
Shared by: a
Shared by: c _                     This is the output now.